# Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php

В общем-то распространенная ошибка, типо сессия не может быть начата, так как заголовки уже отосланы.

```
<?php
        include ("db_connect.php"); //подключаемся к БД
        include ("lib/module_global.php"); //подключаем файл с глобальными функциями

        if($_GET['action'] == "out") out();

        if (login()) //вызываем функцию login, определяющую, авторизирован юзер или нет
        {
            $UID = $_SESSION['id']; //если юзер авторизирован, присвоим переменной $UID его id
            $admin = is_admin($UID); //определяем, админ ли юзер

        }
        else //если пользователь не авторизирован, то проверим, была ли нажата кнопка входа на сайт
        {
            if(isset($_POST['log_in'])) 
            {
                $error = enter(); //функция входа на сайт

                if (count($error) == 0) //если нет ошибок, авторизируем юзера
                {
                    $UID = $_SESSION['id'];

                    $admin = is_admin($UID);
                }
            }
        }
        include ("form.php"); //подключаем файл с формой
```

?>

Проверял, никаких символов до

```
   function login() {   
   ini_set ("session.use_trans_sid", true);     session_start();  
       if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) { //если сесcия есть             
           if(isset($_COOKIE['login']) && isset($_COOKIE['password']))       {        //если cookie есть, то просто обновим время их жизни и вернём true                
        SetCookie("login", "", time() - 1, '/');    
        SetCookie("password","", time() - 1, '/');          
        setcookie ("login", $_COOKIE['login'], time() + 50000, '/');            
        setcookie ("password", $_COOKIE['password'], time() + 50000, '/');          

        $id = $_SESSION['id'];                  
        return true;        
    }
    else { //иначе добавим cookie с логином и паролем, чтобы после перезапуска браузера сессия не слетала               
        $rez = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='{$_SESSION['id']}'"); //запрашиваем строку с искомым id           

        if (mysql_num_rows($rez) == 1) {//если получена одна строка             {       
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rez); //записываем её в ассоциативный массив              
        setcookie ("login", $row['login'], time()+50000, '/');              
        setcookie ("password", md5($row['login'].$row['password']), time() + 50000, '/'); 

        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        return true;            
        } 
        else {
            return false;   
        }                   
}   
if(isset($_COOKIE['login']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) { //если куки существуют.       
    $rez = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='{$_COOKIE['login']}'"); //запрашиваем строку с искомым логином и паролем           
    @$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rez);            

    if(@mysql_num_rows($rez) == 1 && md5($row['login'].$row['password']) == $_COOKIE['password']) {//если логин и пароль нашлись в БД                       
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id']; //записываем в сесиию id              
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];                          
        return true;            
    } 
}
else //если данные из cookie не подошли, то удаляем эти куки, они такие нам не нужны            
        {               
        SetCookie("login", "", time() - 360000, '/');               
        SetCookie("password", "", time() - 360000, '/');                    
        return false;           

        }       
}       
else //если куки не существуют      
{           
    return false;       
}
```

}

Comment: где у вас строчка с session_start() ?? 

приведите код этих файлов db_connect.php, module_global.php

Comment: Я тоже не вижу строчки `session_start();`. Для работы сессий, функция `session_start();` должна вызываться на каждой открываемой странице.

Comment: Было две ошибки. db_connect пересохранил без BOM. 1 ошибка пропала, осталась Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent.

session_start(); вызывается в module_global.php

Comment: Еще кое-что. Если отдельно вынести скрипт (который первый в начале моего вопроса)в отдельный файл. Ошибок нет. Но если он в составе с html тегами. http://jsfiddle.net/Dw4eP/  То ошибка

Comment: Ну так у вас же по ссылке сразу идет ХТМЛ а затем ПХП, что вы еще хотите?
также если файл содержит только php скрипт, то хорошей практикой является не закрывать его тегом "?>"

Comment: Как мне быть тогда, если нужно, чтобы скрипт выполнился в этом месте

Comment: Значит у вас плохо продуманная архитектура. Сначала нужно получить все данные, необходимые для отправки перед контентом (хидеры, куки и тп), сохраняя их в пременные, а только затем начинать вывод ХТМЛ в броузер, подставляя в нужных местах проверки и переменные. Тоесть к выводу первого символа, вы уже должны знать все о странице, которую формируете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте `session_start()` в самом начале `index.php`.

Comment: Поставил. Теперь говорит, что сессия не может запустится на линии 3, так как заголовки уже отправлены на линии 1, а на линии 1 только <?php

Comment: <?php session_start();?> стоит в самом самом начале index.php.
Ну и ошибка:
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at Z:\home\localhost\www\site\index.php:1) in Z:\home\localhost\www\site\index.php on line 1

Comment: @js_cbs, а кодировка какая? UTF-8 with BOM?

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте редактор типа [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.6.4.html) и сохраните все ваши страницы в UTF-8 **without BOM**

Comment: Если я index.php сохраняю без BOM. То строчки меню, информация уже в закорючках получается

Comment: @js_cbs, значит где-то кодировка неверная. проверяйте все

Comment: Ну тогда главный совет - пишите код в специализированных редакторах и IDE! Если русские символы отображаются закорючками, то посылайте броузеру хидер с нужной кодировкой в ручную, так как указание кодировки в мета ХТМЛ как правило недостаточно - http://hashcode.ru/questions/295847#295870

Comment: Скажите, как быть, если требуется запускать сессию, только после определенных проверок, т.е. после того как пользователь отправил данные для авторизации и др.?
К тому же я сейчас принудительно через header установил кодировку, но тут ясно видно, что header до сессии отправляется

Comment: @js_cbs, в Notepad++:

Кодировка -> Преобразовать в utf... (именно преобразовать, а не просто "Кодировать в UTF-8 без BOM")

Comment: Да делал, закорючки говорю

Comment: Вот блин. Текст, который уже написан русскими придётся заново переписывать. Структура файла у тебя должна быть такая:

    <?php
        ... code ...
        if('ваше условие')
            session_start();
        ... code ...
    ?>
    <html>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        ... html-code ...
    </html>

Что тут сложного?
Воспользуйся шаблонизатором (например `Smarty`). Смешивать php и html в одном файле - неблагодарное дело!
Пользуюсь редакторами `Notepad++` и `Dreanweaver` - проблем никаких с кодировкой.